# How to get children of custom component from parent

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I am trying to get children of a custom written component using this code below:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'custom-comp',
  templateUrl: '<div class='child1'></div><div class='child2'></div>',
  styleUrls: ['./custom-comp.component.scss']
})
@Component({
      selector: 'comp',
      templateUrl: '<#custom-comp custom-comp></custom-comp>',
      styleUrls: ['./custom-comp.component.scss']
    })

@ViewChild('custom-comp') custom-comp: ElementRef;
ngOnInit(){
    console.log(this.custom-comp.nativeElement.children);
}
```

It returns this error:
Cannot read property 'children' of undefined

Concluding that this approach only works for native HTML elements, how i can do it for custom components? Thanks !

Comment: You need to move your logging from `ngOnInit` to `ngAfterViewInit`. The `ViewChild` decorated properties are not reliably available until after the view is initialized.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using `nativeElement.children`, I would use the `@ViewChildren` decorator in the custom component to make the children components available in a property on the `CustomComponent`, let's call it `myChildren`, like this:

```
class CustomComponent {
  @ViewChildren(ChildComponent) myChildren: QueryList<ChildComponent>;
}
```

Then use the `@ViewChild` decorator to get the actual component, not just the `ElementRef`:

```
class ParentComponent {
  @ViewChild(CustomComponent) customComp: CustomComponent;
}
```

Then access `myChildren` property on your custom component like this:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  const grandchildren = this.customComp.myChildren;
}
```

This answer makes the simplifying assumption that you know the type of the grand children you want to get and you are not just trying to get "all" the children of your custom component.

A couple of notes:

- **Do not try to access your `@ViewChild` until the [`AfterViewInit`](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit) lifecycle hook.** After seeing @DeborahK's comment, I feel like I should highlight this point more, so I've put it in bold. *This may be the only problem with your current code.*
- Type your `@ViewChild` property as the component itself (`CustomComponent`), not the `ElementRef`.